# How to setup Ubuntu Server on a local wireless network?

Tags: server, virtualbox, ip

I have installed ubuntu server 16.04.3 on virtual box. I am on my college wifi network and I want to setup an ubuntu server locally. 
When I do Ifconfig
I can only see enp0s3 and it returns a inet6 address I can't find a inet address.
Is it that we can only setup ubuntu server through ethernet?.
Can anyone guide me with any reference?

Answer (score 0):

may be better you ask the College Wifi administrator.

You can use the same ip of your laptop/desktop by a NAT interface on Virtual box configuration (By default at creating a new machine). Or if you need a separate address you need to stop the machine and edit configuration and change network properties to Bridge adapter.

I gonna suppose the following:

Laptop/desktop with Virtual box installed and already have access to the wifi network of your College.

You need to know if you are using DHCP or an Static IP.

Suposing the network on your Wifi college is 192.168.1.0/24

Edit /etc/network/interfaces

If using DHCP:

Locate lines relative to enp0s3 and modify to

```
iface enp0s3 inet dhcp
```

If using StaticIP:

Locate lines relative to enp0s3 and modify to

```
iface enp0s3 inet static 
address 192.168.1.110
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

After edit and save the changes you need to restart the network service.

`sudo ifdown enp0s3`
and 
`sudo ifup enp0s3`

or restart the machine.

```
sudo reboot
```

Later make another Ifconfig, and see if you have an ipv4 addres on your virtualmachine.

If not work, check your Host Firewall.